# Comparing versions of values returning only one value and the result tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below I have a table which compares versions from col_A to versions from col_B and returns  true of false if they are similar.

```
Col_A | Col_B    | Col_C | 
---------------------------
val1  | versionA | true  |
val1  | versionB | false |
val1  | versionC | false |
----------------=----------
val2  | versionA | false |
val2  | versionB | false |
val2  | versionC | false |
```

What I am trying to achieve, is if one comparision between Col_A and Col_B returns true, move on, so the above table would be:

```
Col_A | Col_B | 
----------------
val1  | true  |
----------------
val2  | false |
```

Here is my thought process and an example query, except I really do not know where to go from here.

```
SELECT Col_A, Col_B, 
       case when Col_A = Col_B then 'true' else 'false end as Col_C --returns the first table
FROM exTable
```

Would an IF-Statement be appropriate in this scenario to get the second table?

Comment: Is there are reason you can't just do SELECT Col_A, MAX(Col_B) FROM exTable GROUP BY Col_A?

Comment: In previous comment I was assuming exTable had your true/false column. If you don't already have Col_C, I guess what I meant was SELECT Col_A, MAX(case when Col_A = Col_B then 'true' else 'false end) FROM exTable GROUP BY Col_A

Comment: @EdmCoff I will try your idea and see if it will work

Comment: @EdmCoff didn't work, the result I am getting is still the first table

Comment: How is `val1` = `versionA`, while `val1` <> `versionB`?  I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Travis Did you see my correction in my second comment? I had misread your post at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a comparison result using CASE and then group by using MAX.

```
WITH exTable AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('val1', 'val1'),
            ('val1', 'versionB'),
            ('val1', 'versionC'),
            ('val2', 'versionA'),
            ('val2', 'versionB'),
            ('val2', 'versionC')
        ) AS a (Col_A, Col_B)
)
SELECT Col_A,  
      CASE MAX(case when Col_A = Col_B then 1 else 0 end) WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as Col_C
FROM exTable
GROUP BY Col_A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH exTable AS (
        SELECT * FROM (
            VALUES
                ('val1', 'versionA','true'),
                ('val1', 'versionB','false'),
                ('val1', 'versionC','false'),
                ('val2', 'versionA','false'),
                ('val2', 'versionB','false'),
                ('val2', 'versionC','false')
            ) AS a (Col_A, Col_B,Col_C)
    )

    --select * from exTable
    SELECT Col_A,  
          CASE MAX(case when Col_C = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as Col_C
    FROM exTable
    GROUP BY Col_A
```